# Is there a way to deploy multiple zip packages from a folder of the artifacts using Azure Web App deployment task in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, release, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

There are multiple CS project packages in a folder of my artifacts that needs to be deployed into the web app with multiple Virtual Directories. When I give "`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/*/*/APIs/*.zip`" as my Package/Folder pattern to deploy it says"

> Error: More than one package matched with specified pattern:
>   C:\agent_work\r8\a**\APIs*.zip. Please restrain the search
>   pattern.

Comment: If you have multiple packages, why not package all of them in a single zip file and then deploy?

Comment: Is there a way to package all the API folders as 1 package during the build time itself? For now, I'm copying all the APIs into one folder and packaging it into a single ZIP using PS as a post build step.

Answer (score 0):

You can try unzip your package first in current directory :

```
Unzip "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Package.PackageName)" "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Build\Package"
```

then give the path to your folder like this instead of '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/*/*/APIs/*.zip' :

```
Build\Package\web
```

Virtual Directory creation is separate part. You can create virtual directory before deploy web app content.